# If two random variables have the same distribution, how to show after subtracting a common r.v., they still have the same distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, generating-functions

The question goes, if $X, Y, Z$ are independent random variables, where $Z$ is normal, and $X+Z, Y+Z$ have the same distribution, show $X, Y$ have the same distribution. I don't know whether and how generating functions can help, because $X+Z$ and $Z$ are not independent, and I cannot argue by subtracting $Z$ from $X+Z$. Could anyone please give any hint?

More generally, is it true when we don't assume $Z$ is normal?

Comment: This is not true. in the  general case.  There is a counter-example in Feller's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy proof when $Z$ is normal is using characteristic functions. Let $f,g,h$ be the characteristic functions of $X,Y$ and $Z$ respectively. Then $f(t)h(t)=h(t)g(t)$ and  $h(t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ so $f=g$ which implies that $X$ and $Y$ have the same characteristic function.

This is not true. in the general case. See Curiosities ii) in under "Special densities: mixtures"in Vol II (Ch. on  characteristic functions) in  Feller's book.

Comment: So normality of $Z$ can be replaced with "has a nonzero characteristic function"?

Comment: @angryavian Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, can you show that $X + Z$ and $Y + Z$ have the same distribution for $Z$ normal with $X,Y$ and $Z$ independent? Call this Claim 1.

If so, since $X + Z$ and $Y + Z$ have the same distribution, add the normal distribution $-Z$ to $X + Z$ and $Y + Z$, by Claim 1 the resulting distributions are the same (namely, $X$ and $Y$ are the same).